# How to use not exists instead of inner join?

Tags: mysql

**Exercise Question:**

Use a NOT EXISTS clause to examine all the users in the dogs table that are not in the users table.

I can get the correct answer using the following inner join:

```
select d.user_guid as UserID, d.dog_guid as DogID 
from dogs d
left join users u
on d.user_guid = u.user_guid
where u.user_guid is null;
```

However, I cannot get the correct answer with the 'Not Exists' sub-query:

```
select d.user_guid as dUserID, d.dog_guid as dDogID
from dogs d
where not exists (select distinct u.user_guid from users u);
```

The output of my wrong query above:

```
+---------+--------+
| dUserID | dDogID |
+---------+--------+
```

The Answer Query:

```
select d.user_guid as dUserID, d.dog_guid as dDogID
from dogs d
where not exists (select distinct u.user_guid 
                  from users u 
                  where u.user_guid = d.user_guid);
```

The Answer Output:

```
+---------+--------------------------------------+
| dUserID | dDogID                               |
+---------+--------------------------------------+
| None    | fd7c0a66-7144-11e5-ba71-058fbc01cf0b |
+---------+--------------------------------------+
| None    | fdbb6b7a-7144-11e5-ba71-058fbc01cf0b |
+---------+--------------------------------------+
```

I'd like to know what possible reasons are why my `Not Exists` sub-query is wrong without `u.user_guid = d.user_guid` in `where` clause.

Comment: Your non-working query returns false because there are some records in users, The second query is more specific (a correlated sub query) which checks  that there is a guid match and returns true if there is no match.

Comment: You can safely simplify your subquery like `... where not exists (select 1 from from users u where u.user_guid = d.user_guid)`.

Answer (score 1):

because `not exists (select distinct u.user_guid from users u)` always return false

you can try `NOT IN` like this

```
SELECT
    d.user_guid AS dUserID,
    d.dog_guid AS dDogID
FROM
    dogs d
WHERE
    d.user_guid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT u.user_guid FROM user AS u);
```